# multi threaded Splitter in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using spring integration to fetch records through tcp. There is a collection of client ids, getting split into individual client id messages to fetch respective records. This works fine as of now.
Now, to improve the performance, I need to break the collection into sub collections and use client ids from sub collection to fetch records.
I've implemented splitter to break the collection, but its working for only one thread. program ends after servicing first request only i.e. first collection of clients.

How can i implement the scenario using multithreading ?

Answer (score 2):

Just make an output  channel of your splitter as [an Executor one](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-executorchannel):

```
<int:channel id="executorChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="someExecutor"/>
</int:channel>
```

Comment: The scenario is a bit different, request message after splitter channel is routed to 2 different channels to create 2 different messages and then passed to service. I had already tried using task executor at splitter channel as well as configured task executor on routed channels, but each thread exits after servicing the first message.

Comment: Can explain a bit more what does `program end` (or `each thread exits`) mean? Maybe you just run a unit test? So, you should block a main test's thread to get results. Actually, we use some `PollableChannel` to wait reply from unit tests. If you run your code as `main` java method you should get good results. And you mentioned that you split several times. So, make all output channels of splitters as ExecutorChannel.

Comment: please find below the configuration and the scenario

Comment: I am using System.exit(0) at the end of the main class. when I remove System.exit(0), all the threads run properly and I get desired results, But the main program never stops i.e. main thread never dies.

Comment: Right. It shouldn't die, because via taskExecutor you start other thread and the management comes back to the main thread and your `System.exit(0)` kills all threads. Actually I don't understand a reason of such application. Tipically Spring Integration processes live in some container like Tomcat or Spring XD. Don't forget that you can kill your main Java process from OS. So, move your solution to your main application and that's all.

Comment: "Don't forget that you can kill your main Java process from OS. So, move your solution to your main application", what does it mean? I am using shell script to execute the main class which is terminated with System.exit(0). I still do not get the proposed solution

Comment: So, you should wait some complition of your underlying tasks in threads, before call `System.exit(0)`. E.g. `CountDownLatch`. Here you should keep in mind that your application should not exit immediately, if it start separate threads and if you are interested in complition of those tasks.

Comment: exactly, thats what I am trying to do. will update you on successful completion.

Comment: To use gateway as sync gateway, Future objects are used on interface. Do we also need to define async-executor in config? I've configured gateway as sync gateway by configuring "async-executor" with task executor. But still the requests are flown and serviced by Main thread, so i configured splitter channel with another task executor and its working fine till a certain period of time. Then after that everything gets parked, nothing gets processed, executor queue size contains remaining messages, active threads are also proper...I tried to configure gateway timeouts, but that didn't help.!!!

Comment: Gateway's async-executor works only for methods with Future return type. If you are waiting a response from gateway (even if it is a Future), your downstream flow should return anything anyway. If you splitt message, you should aggregate the result for gateway's reply. Anyway it looks like separate Question

Comment: yes, I am returning Future return type and aggregating the results. But have no idea why execution halts in between, executor threads are active and queue is also filled. Do i need to raise a separate question for this?

Comment: Yes. And provide your configuration too, please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520269/execution-process-gets-halted-after-certain-period-with-executor-still-active-an