# Execution process gets halted after certain period with executor still active and its queue count fixed

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I've configured tcp call in spring integration with following flow:
Gateway(Future call)====>Splitter(with executor)====>router(to 2 different transformers)===>Outboud-gateway===>Aggregator====>service

Aggregator is configured on receiving the reply because need to make another tcp call based on particular value received from first call, then send to service class.

I am getting problem after certain period of execution (records properly getting persisted) when everything halts, executor active count reaches max pool size and executor queue contains queued messages, and everything just halts forever and need to terminate the main process.

```
<int:gateway id="clientPositionsGateway" service-interface="com.example.ClientPositionsGateway" async-executor="syncExecutor">
    <int:method name="fetchClientPositions" request-channel="clientPositionsRequestChannel" reply-channel="clientPositionsResponseChannel"/>
    <int:method name="getSecurityData" request-channel="securityDataRequestChannel" reply-channel="clientPositionsResponseChannel"/>
</int:gateway>

<int:channel id="clientPositionsRequestChannel" >

</int:channel>
<int:channel id="securityDataRequestChannel" >

</int:channel>

<int:splitter input-channel="clientPositionsRequestChannel" 
        output-channel="singleClientPositionsRequestChannel" 

         />

<int:channel id="singleClientPositionsRequestChannel" >
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<int:recipient-list-router input-channel="singleClientPositionsRequestChannel" >
    <int:recipient channel="singleClientCommQueryChannel" />
    <int:recipient channel="singleClientTransQueryChannel" />
</int:recipient-list-router>

<int:transformer
    input-channel="singleClientTransQueryChannel"
    output-channel="transQueryHeaderEnricherRequestChannel"
    ref="dmPOSBaseTransQueryTransformer" order="2"/>

<int:header-enricher id="transQueryHeaderEnricher" input-channel="transQueryHeaderEnricherRequestChannel" output-channel="dmQueryRequestChannel" >
     <int:header name="transQueryHeader" value="TRANS_QUERY_HEADER"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<int:channel id="transQueryHeaderEnricherRequestChannel" >

</int:channel>

<int:transformer
    input-channel="singleClientCommQueryChannel"
    output-channel="dmQueryRequestChannel"
    ref="dmPOSBaseCommQueryTransformer" order="1"/>

<int:transformer
    input-channel="securityDataRequestChannel"
    output-channel="secQueryHeaderEnricherRequestChannel"
    ref="dmSECBaseQueryTransformer" />

<int:header-enricher id="secQueryHeaderEnricher" input-channel="secQueryHeaderEnricherRequestChannel" output-channel="dmQueryRequestChannel" >
     <int:header name="secQueryHeader" value="SEC_QUERY_HEADER"/>
</int:header-enricher>        

<int:channel id="singleClientCommQueryChannel" >

</int:channel>
<int:channel id="transformSecurityDataRequestChannel" />
<int:channel id="singleClientTransQueryChannel" >

</int:channel>
<int:channel id="dmQueryRequestChannel" >

</int:channel>

<int:channel id="secQueryHeaderEnricherRequestChannel" >

</int:channel>

<ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="dmServerGateway" 
       request-channel="dmQueryRequestChannel" 
       reply-channel="dmQueryResponseChannel"
       connection-factory="csClient" 
       reply-timeout="3600000" request-timeout="3600000"
       />

<int:aggregator input-channel="dmQueryResponseChannel"  
    method="aggregateClientPositions"
    ref="clientPositionsAggregator" 
    output-channel="aggregateDataResponseChannel"
    correlation-strategy-expression="headers[id]"
    release-strategy-expression="size() == 1"
    send-partial-result-on-expiry="true" />

<int:service-activator method="createClientPosition" input-channel="aggregateDataResponseChannel" output-channel="clientPositionsResponseChannel" ref="clientPositionsService" >
</int:service-activator>

<int:channel id="dmQueryResponseChannel" >

</int:channel>
<int:channel id="securityDataResponseChannel" />
<int:channel id="aggregateDataResponseChannel" >

</int:channel>

<int:channel id="clientPositionsResponseChannel" >
```

Here are gateway interface methods:
Future> fetchClientPositions(List clientList);
List getSecurityData(String symbol);

Comment: What version of Spring Integration are you using?  What is the configuration of `csClient`? An hour is a rather long time to wait for a reply. Take a thread dump (jstack or VisualVM) to see what the executor threads are doing.

Comment: using spring-integration-2.2 .     <ip:tcp-connection-factory id="csClient" 
           type="client" 
           host="${DM_SERVER_${REGION}}"
           port="${DM_PORT_${REGION}}"
           single-use="true"
     deserializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize" />

Comment: when I remove task executor from splitter channel, everything is running properly but it becomes single threaded.

Comment: OK; the key is single-use; if it was false, the other executor threads would be waiting to get the connection (for up to an hour) if the current thread is still waiting for a reply. With `true`, each thread gets its own socket; if all the threads are in use (and you have queued requests, it is likely they are all waiting for a reply. Like I said, a thread dump will make it clear what's happening.

Comment: I configured aggregator after service activator call, and things are working fine now. But I am facing issue when I use asynchronous gateway. In this case, some messages go on missing. I observed that only one asynchronous executor is running.

Comment: I suggest you start a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your TCP service is bottleneck.

From other side I don't understand a bit your message flow:

1. You have `splitter`, so your payload may be a `List`
2. you use `recipient-list-router` and here duplicate each item after splitting
3. Both recipients end up on `tcp:outbound-gateway`, but one by one, because both are within direct channels.
4. `tcp:outbound-gateway` sends a reply to the `aggregator`. But the last one has strange aggregation configuration: each group contains only one message by its `id`, and completes as a list with one message
5. `aggregator` sends reply (over `service-activator`) exactly to the gateway's `reply-channel`

So, how about other splitted items? They will be lost, because your gateway already has got reply just after first message. All other work seems redundant...

Comment: splitter splits list, each item or sub list is then passed to 2 different transformers through router to create 2 different actual messages. Then these 2 messages are flown to server via tcp. I am using aggregator to receive reply which is list of messages in a string fromat, so based on some reply string value, again a different message is created and being sent to server via tcp in aggregator itself. Then an entity is created and being sent to service to be validated and persisted. The design looks complex and weird but needs to be followed as per the requirement is.

Comment: Also, It runs with single thread, all steps get completed well, but main problem is the performance. I need to multithread it to improve the time execution.

Comment: Right, it runs with single thread, because everything works withing caller thread and it hides a bottleneck. Don't understand how your aggregator can completes a list, if your correlation is just a message ID... Try to decouple your logic from aggregator. He must not do some busines step, as you said TCP stuff...

Comment: One question, is aggregator always required to be configured when using splitter? what if each request needs to be serviced separately? in this case, can we remove aggregator?

Comment: Yes you can, but is the reason of two-way gateway in this case? If you send a message to split and wait response, you have to aggregate results for all items, otherwise it doesn't make sense: first item returns a result to the gateway and how about others? They will be lost

Comment: I do not know if its a good practice to configure aggregator which doesn't do anything but return incoming object. can I apply this?

Comment: I've configured as you mentioned with aggregator just acting as medium to get passed. It is simply not doing anything, just returning incoming object and everything is now working fine only when I am using synchronous gateway. when I apply Future return types on returning object of interface method, many messages go on missing. Program runs fine for queued messages and terminates properly, but wondered where all other messages are gone !!!